# How can i overlap 3 divs in css but be partially visible

Tags: html, css

I want to overlap 3 Wallet divisions in css and i want it to be partially visible but it somehow doesnt work. One wallet should be fully visible at the top and the other 3 wallets should be overlapped with each wallet being visible at the top.

```
 `    <div id="main-wallet" class="wallet-config">
                <p class="wallet-name">Wallet Haushalt</p>
                <p class="wallet-balance positive-balance">500,85 €</p>
            </div>
            <div id="wallet2" class="wallet-config">
                <p class="wallet-name">Wallet Einkauf</p>
            <p class="wallet-balance positive-balance">56,11 €</p>
        </div>
        <div id="wallet3" class="wallet-config">
            <p class="wallet-name">Wallet Gehalt</p>
            <p class="wallet-balance positive-balance">8.053,75 €</p>
        </div>
        <div id="wallet4" class="wallet-config">
            <p class="wallet-name">Wallet Sohn</p>
            <p class="wallet-balance negative-balance">-42,45 €</p>
        </div>`
```

Comment: Post as a [mcve] with CSS.

Comment: "*I want to overlap 3 Wallet divisions...*" and "*One wallet should be fully visible at the top and the other 3 wallets*" - do you have three, or four "wallets"? "*One wallet should be fully visible at the top and the other 3 wallets should be overlapped with each wallet being visible at the top.*" - I can't understand this description, one should be fully visible, with the others overlapping and also being visible at the top? You need to give details as to what - precisely - you want to achieve.

Comment: What you mean by partially visible? I think you are looking for `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);`.

Comment: Maybe you could also use `filter: opacity(0.8)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many options, you could use position absolute and z-index to achieve this goal, or use transform: translate(x,y) to do the trick, right element order will do the same thing as z-index do